# Babel Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I just wanted start a new project using babel and ES2016 so i can use await async in new project. In babelrc i put following:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2016",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

And than in index.js i have:

```
require('babel-core/register')()
require('babel-polyfill')
require('./bin/server.js')
```

But now in server.js it fails when i run the app, at first line because of import:

> import Koa from 'koa'

Saying that it does not recognize "import". The packages i installed are babe-cli, core, polyfill,preset-es2016, preset-stage-0 and babel-register. Am i missing something or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to install npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015

Comment: But with that i will use ES2015 (ES6).

Comment: Firstly ES2016 != ES6, as ES6 === ES2015. As ES7 === ES2016.

Comment: Yea my mistake :)